# Cleanest way to truncate last items in a comma delimited string?

Tags: c#

What is the best/cleanest way you know of to take a comma delimited string, such as "A,B,C,D,E,F,G", and return only the 1st x amount of items in the list? So if x = 5 then the result would be "A,B,C,D,E".

I know there are different ways to do this: "for loop" counting commas, then truncate string; split string to array or list, then remove last x amount of items.

Is there a cleaner, more efficient option that I don't know of? How would you go about this?

Thanks in advance!!
Greg

Comment: You mention counting commas, splitting the string, and removing the end. Are you looking for a way independent of these three methods, or where you intending that list to be thought of as a single method of accomplishing this?

Comment: The Take method is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks all!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would split the task into two parts:

- Splitting the string by commas
- Taking only the first N values

Fortunately C# makes both of these pretty simple, with [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) handling the first, and the LINQ [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) method handling the second:

```
var items = text.Split(',')
                .Take(itemLimit);
```

Or if you want to create a list:

```
var items = text.Split(',')
                .Take(itemLimit)
                .ToList();
```

I would *not* convert it back into a comma-delimited string unless you really need to. Keep the most natural representation of the data (e.g. a `List<string>`) for as long as you can. If you need to, just use `String.Join`.

You could *potentially* make the `Split` part more efficient by writing a "lazy splitter" - but it would be work for very little gain, IMO, unless you expect to get a very long string and only want to keep a few items. It would look *something* like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> LazySplit(this string text, string separator)
{
    int start = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int end = text.IndexOf(separator, start);
        if (end == -1)
        {
            // Note: if the string ends with the separator, this will yield
            // an empty string
            yield return text.Substring(start);
            yield break; // This will terminate the otherwise-infinite loop
        }
        yield return text.Substring(start, end - start);
        start = end + separator.Length;
    }
}
```

Then the usage code is similar to before:

```
var items = text.LazySplit(",")
                .Take(itemLimit)
                .ToList();
```

Alternatively, if you *really, really* need to keep it in a string, you could just write something to find the Nth comma, and just use `Substring` to take the first part of the string:

```
// TODO: Improve the name :)
public static string TruncateAfterSeparatorCount(string text,
                                                 string separator,
                                                 int count)
{
    // We pretend that the string "starts" with a separator before index 0.
    int index = -separator.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int nextIndex = text.IndexOf(separator, index + separator.Length);
        // Not enough separators. Return the whole string. Could throw instead.
        if (nextIndex == -1)
        {
            return text;
        }
        index = nextIndex;
    }
    // We need to handle the count == 0 case, where index will be negative...
    return text.Substring(0, Math.Max(index, 0));
}
```

But as I say, I would personally try to use the `List<string>` approach if possible. The above code is clearly significantly more complex than `Split`/`Take`/`ToList`, even though it's more efficient. Only use more efficient but more complicated code when you've proved there's a need.

Comment: A method other than the ones you listed was asked for.

Comment: @PhillipNordwall: Where? I don't see anything mentioning Take in the question.

Comment: Counting commas was mentioned, as was using split. Then a cleaner method was asked for.

Comment: @PhillipNordwall: How does `Take` count the commas? It counts elements returned by Split. I believe that's the cleanest approach available.

Comment: I agree it is a clean approach. I may have misread this question, and have asked a clarifying question. I took the question to have constraints 3 constraints. Not counting commas, not splitting to an array or list, and not removing the last x items.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
string.Join("," , str.Split(",").Take(5));
```

Or, if you do it regularly, you can write an extension method just for that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b873y76a.aspx) and a [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb503062.aspx).

Try this:

```
string yourString = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G";
List<string> items = yourString.Split(',')
    .Take(5)
    .ToList();
string output = string.Join(",", items);
```

Comment: I don't believe that will compile at the moment due to the Where clause - which I believe is unnecessary.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yeah I didn't originally have it in, then I second guessed whether the `,` would be included in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] words = s.Split(',').Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string[] List = SubList(5);
    string Output = string.Join(",", List);

private string[] SubList(int p)
{
    string[] List = new string[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
    string[] List2 = new string[p];
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        List2[i] = List[i];
    return List2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you want to do it with just `String` methods (not Take()):

```
string.Join(",", s.Split(","), 0, 5);
```

If you know each element is only one character, you can do:

```
s.Substring(0, 2*x - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun - using Regex/String methods only (I wouldn't use Regex to do this real world - then I'd have [two problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20842/158564)):

```
string.SubString(0,Regex.Matches(string,",")[x-1].Index);
```